# Query for Results by Enter Key(Not Working) or Search button(Working)

Tags: javascript, html

If I click the search button, the results are appearing on the screen properly.  I want the same result to occur also by typing in the text box and pressing the enter key.  The problem is the results are not appearing when I press enter.  Anyone know how I can fix this.   Thanks

Here is the code

```
    <input id="address" type="text" value="Paramus, NJ" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();" />
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="mdiv">
  <div class="mdiv">
    <div class="md">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vj0cpv0c/4/) with problem

Comment: Put the inputs in a form, call *codeAddress* using the form's submit handler. Change the input type button to input type submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the inputs into a form, put the listener on the form's submit listener, change the button to a submit button and remove its listener:

```
<form onsubmit="codeAddress(); return false;" action="...">
  <input id="address" type="text" value="Paramus, NJ">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Since currently the page may not navigate anywhere, I've added `return false` to the listener.

Comment: A little depressing  that I spent hours trying to figure that out and it took you about 20 seconds.  Works great,  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @VinceGOGO—well, that has been the default way to do things for a very long time… ;-)